# Powershell Access user liste for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, office-365

I would like to have a SharePoint online report for all users groups site, sub sites,library,items.

For example: a user : Tood , i would like to know all the groups that he belongs to,all permission on all elements of a site.

and save it on an CSV file.

if you can help me with the code i would really appreciate it. if no just give me some ideas. Or should i do it with c#?.

Thanks

Comment: have a look at this link
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/powershell-commands-to-check-permission-for-a-specific-user-on-all-sharepoint-o

Comment: You want for particular site collection?

Comment: yes please .i will appreciate if you can help