# FBA Access Review

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

We are using the Microsoft SQL forms provider to grant access to external users on a SP2010 Enterprise server.

We have installed a codeplex solution "[SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/)" that allows us to manage the FBA users from our root site collection.

I now need to find out which FBA users have access to certain roles but I cannot seem to find out any easy way as under role management it just gives a number of users in the role and does not show the users names.

If anyone has any experience with this codeplex solution or know of a query that can be performed on the SQL FBA database that can return the information required that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not give you a site in the GUI, which permissions have been assigned to a specific user. It does not matter if this user is a FBA- or Domain-Account.

You have to navigate manually to each page and check permissions there. 3rd party tools or [PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81100/powershell-script-to-find-permissions-for-a-specific-user) might help you out.