# Retrieve list of a user’s permissions in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, permissions, 2016, item-level-permissions

Is there any way in SharePoint 2016 to get a full list of *all* permissions that has been granted to a user?

I.e. a list including the permissions that is set on the object level. For example: if Alice has granted Bob direct access to the document "Financial Report Q4" that would also show up in the list.

Could such a list be retrieved via PowerShell? Or is there some kind of audit functionality that is built-in to SharePoint?

It would be great to be able to retrieve this information without needing to buy a third-party tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below PowerShell.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
 
#Function to retrieve Permission data 
Function Get-PermissionInfo([String]$UserID, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject]$Object) 
{ 
    #Object Array to hold Permission data 
    $PermissionDataCollection = @() 
 
    #Determine the given Object type and Get URL of it 
    switch($Object.GetType().FullName) 
    { 
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb"  { $ObjectType = "Site" ; $ObjectURL = $Object.URL } 
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem"  
        {  
            if($Object.Folder -ne $null) 
            { 
                 $ObjectType = "Folder" ; $ObjectURL = "$($Object.Web.Url)/$($Object.Url)"  
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $ObjectType = "List Item"; $ObjectURL = "$($Object.Web.Url)/$($Object.Url)"  
            } 
        } 
        #Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary, "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPPictureLibrary",etc 
        default { $ObjectType = "List/Library"; $ObjectURL = "$($Object.ParentWeb.Url)/$($Object.RootFolder.URL)" } 
    } 
     
    #Get Permissions of the user on given object - Such as: Web, List, Folder, ListItem 
    $UserPermissionInfo = $Object.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo($UserID) 
    #Iterate through each permission and get the details 
    foreach($UserRoleAssignment in $UserPermissionInfo.RoleAssignments) 
    { 
        #Get all permission levels assigned to User account directly or via SharePOint Group 
        $UserPermissions=@() 
        foreach ($UserRoleDefinition in $UserRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) 
        { 
            #Exclude "Limited Accesses" 
            if($UserRoleDefinition.Name -ne "Limited Access") 
            { 
                $UserPermissions += $UserRoleDefinition.Name 
            } 
        } 
     
        #Determine Permissions granted directly or through SharePoint Group 
        if($UserPermissions) 
        { 
            if($UserRoleAssignment.Member -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroup])    
            { 
                 $PermissionType = "Member of SharePoint Group: " + $UserRoleAssignment.Member.Name                  
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $PermissionType = "Direct Permission" 
            } 
            $UserPermissions = $UserPermissions -join ";"      
     
            #Create an object to hold storage data 
            $PermissionData = New-Object PSObject 
            $PermissionData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Object" -value $ObjectType 
            $PermissionData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $Object.Title 
            $PermissionData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "URL" -value $ObjectURL         
            $PermissionData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Permission Type" -value $PermissionType 
            $PermissionData | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Permissions" -value $UserPermissions 
            $PermissionDataCollection += $PermissionData 
        }             
    }     
    Return $PermissionDataCollection 
} 
 
#Function to Generate Permission Report 
Function Generate-PermissionReport($UserID, $WebAppURL, $ReportPath) 
{ 
    #Output Report location, delete the file, If already exist! 
    if (Test-Path $ReportPath) 
     { 
        Remove-Item $ReportPath 
     } 
      
      #Write Output Report CSV File Headers 
     "Object, Title, URL, Permission Type, Permissions" | out-file $ReportPath 
 
    ###Check Whether the Search Users is a Farm Administrator ### 
    Write-host "Scanning Farm Administrators..."  
      #Get the SharePoint Central Administration site 
      $AdminWebApp = Get-SPwebapplication -includecentraladministration | where {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication} 
    $AdminSite = Get-SPWeb $AdminWebApp.Url 
    $AdminGroupName = $AdminSite.AssociatedOwnerGroup 
    $FarmAdminGroup = $AdminSite.SiteGroups[$AdminGroupName] 
  
    #enumerate in farm adminidtrators groups 
    foreach ($user in $FarmAdminGroup.users) 
    { 
        if($user.LoginName.Endswith($UserID,1)) #1 to Ignore Case 
        { 
                "Farm, $($AdminSite.Title), $($AdminWebApp.URL), Farm Administrators Group, Farm Administrator" | Out-File $ReportPath -Append 
        }      
    } 
  
    ### Check Web Application User Policies ### 
    Write-host "Scanning Web Application Policies..."  
     $WebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebAppURL 
  
        foreach ($Policy in $WebApp.Policies) 
        { 
            #Check if the search users is member of the group 
              if($Policy.UserName.EndsWith($UserID,1)) 
             { 
                #Write-Host $Policy.UserName 
                 $PolicyRoles=@() 
                foreach($Role in $Policy.PolicyRoleBindings) 
                { 
                    $PolicyRoles+= $Role.Name +";" 
                } 
            #Send Data to CSV File 
            "Web Application, $($WebApp.Name), $($WebApp.URL), Web Application Policy, $($PolicyRoles)" | Out-File $ReportPath -Append 
            } 
        } 
 
    #Convert UserID Into Claims format - If WebApp is claims based! Domain\User to i:0#.w|Domain\User 
    if($WebApp.UseClaimsAuthentication) 
    { 
        $ClaimsUserID = (New-SPClaimsPrincipal -identity $UserID -identitytype 1).ToEncodedString() 
    } 
     
    #Get all Site collections of given web app 
    $SiteCollections = Get-SPSite -WebApplication $WebAppURL -Limit All 
 
    #Loop through all site collections  
    foreach($Site in $SiteCollections) 
    { 
        Write-host "Scanning Site Collection:" $site.Url 
        ###Check Whether the User is a Site Collection Administrator 
           foreach($SiteCollAdmin in $Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators) 
        { 
            if($SiteCollAdmin.LoginName.EndsWith($ClaimsUserID,1)) 
               { 
                "Site Collection, $($Site.RootWeb.Title), $($Site.RootWeb.Url), Site Collection Administrators Group, Site Collection Administrator" | Out-File $ReportPath -Append 
               }      
          } 
         
        #Get all webs 
        $WebsCollection = $Site.AllWebs 
        #Loop throuh each Site (web) 
        foreach($Web in $WebsCollection) 
        { 
                   if($Web.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True) 
                { 
                    Write-host "Scanning Site:" $Web.Url 
                 
                    #Get Permissions of the user on Web 
                    $WebPermissions = Get-PermissionInfo $ClaimsUserID $Web 
                     
                    #Export Web permission data to CSV file - Append 
                    $WebPermissions |  Export-csv $ReportPath  -notypeinformation -Append  
                }     
                 
                #Check Lists with Unique Permissions 
                Write-host "Scanning Lists on $($web.url)..." 
                foreach($List in $web.Lists) 
                { 
                    if($List.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True -and ($List.Hidden -eq $false)) 
                    { 
                        #Get Permissions of the user on list 
                        $ListPermissions = Get-PermissionInfo $ClaimsUserID $List 
                         
                        #Export Web permission data to CSV file - Append 
                        $ListPermissions |  Export-csv $ReportPath -notypeinformation -Append                          
                    } 
                 
                    #Check Folders with Unique Permissions 
                    $UniqueFolders = $List.Folders | where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True }                     
                    #Get Folder permissions 
                    foreach($folder in $UniqueFolders) 
                    { 
                        $FolderPermissions = Get-PermissionInfo $ClaimsUserID $folder 
                 
                        #Export Folder permission data to CSV file - Append 
                        $FolderPermissions |  Export-csv $ReportPath -notypeinformation -Append                 
                    } 
                 
                    #Check List Items with Unique Permissions 
                    $UniqueItems = $List.Items | where { $_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True } 
                    #Get Item level permissions 
                    foreach($item in $UniqueItems) 
                    { 
                        $ItemPermissions = Get-PermissionInfo $ClaimsUserID $Item 
                         
                        #Export List Items permission data to CSV file - Append 
                        $ItemPermissions |  Export-csv $ReportPath -notypeinformation -Append              
                    } 
                } 
        } 
    } 
    Write-Host Permission Report Generated successfully! 
} 
 
#Input Variables 
$WebAppURL = "http://intranet.crescent.com" 
$Userid ="Crescent\Salaudeen"  
$ReportPath = "D:\Reports\PermissionRpt.csv" 
 
#Call the function to generate user access report 
Generate-PermissionReport $Userid $WebAppURL $ReportPath
```

Reference:
[SharePoint Permission Report: Find Access Rights for Specific User in Farm](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Permission-2840f327)

Comment: Thank you Emily. I will try this ASAP.

Comment: If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I can’t seem to get out correct data from that script. Do you by any chance have any mock data with screenshots to show examples of what the script can do?

Comment: Ah. I had enter incorrect input values. When I entered ”domain\username” it worked fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To get a full list of all **permission levels** that have been granted to a user, You can simply use `Check Permissions` in `Site Permissions`

- Open Site Settings
- Below `User and Permissions`, click on Site `Permissions`
- From the above ribbon, click on `Check Permissions`
- Type, your User or Group Name, and click `Check Now`
- The list of all permissions for this user will be listed as shown below:

[image]

Besides the above simple method, you can use PowerShell to get user permissions as mentioned at [Powershell script to find permissions for a specific user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81100/powershell-script-to-find-permissions-for-a-specific-user)